# How to stop recursive call of Page.DataBind()?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-4.0

I have a public property in my code-behind that I want to bind it to my control in .aspx page. If I use `Page.DataBind()` it works but I don't want to use this as this causes recursive data bind to all controls.

Even if Page.DataBind() had an overloaded method which accepted boolean indicating whether I want to call it recursively or not, it would have been a better option but at the moment it will only degrade performance due to recursion.

My only objective is to bind public/protected properties in my code-behind page to my .aspx page. Is there any better alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess your binding code is somethong like

```
<%# MyProperty %>
```

This kind of binding will occur only if if you call `Page.DataBind()`, but if you write:

```
<%= MyProperty %>
```

then you don't have to call `Page.DataBind()`

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer works for simple display of values, but does not work for using databound values in server tags, e.g.

```
<asp:Literal Visible='<%# IsNewApplication %>' runat="server">New Application</asp:Literal>
```

The only way I have found of getting round this is to use `PlaceHolder` controls to isolate blocks of bindable tags, then called `DataBind()` on the `PlaceHolder`.

It's up to you to determine is this is more or less ugly / appropriate than just setting the visibility in code!

Comment: I have created my own "custom" control which allows both "auto binding" (no need to call `DataBind` manually) and "bind propagation stopping" (because some things shouldn't be data-bound [again]) .. +1 because most of the time I find `<%# .. %>` useful control properties and `<%= .. %>` only rarely useful.

Comment: Yes, the bind propagation stopping would be an extremely handy feature. I normally do it on an ad hoc basis, a control framework like yours would be a definite improvement :o)